# Interpreter for Forth

Tags: haskell

I recently started learning Haskell, and I'm trying to write an interpreter for the FORTH language using Haskell. But I'm having problems trying to run the most basic of operations. For example, a simple program in FORTH (taken as a string in Haskell) would be as follows: "1 2 +" returns a stack containing the integer 3, which in Haskell can be represented a list of ints: [3].

I also have functions to push, drop, and pop elements from the stack. I have an addition function to add two elements from the stack.

Now, having these functions at hand, how can I parse the simple program "1 2 +" in order to return [3]? I would expect the example to look like this:

```
forthInterpreter "1 2 +"
[3]
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Please let me know if you have any clarification questions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every command you have is a function from `Stack -> Stack`. This makes it easy to interpret commands. I'm using a `[Int]` as the type of the `Stack`, with the number on top of the stack at the head of the list.

```
interpretCommand :: String -> [Int] -> [Int]
interpretCommand "+" = lift2 (+)
interpretCommand "-" = lift2 (-)
interpretCommand "*" = lift2 (*)
interpretCommand "/" = lift2 div
interpretCommand "MOD" = lift2 mod
interpretCommand number = \zs -> read number : zs
```

where `lift2` lifts a 2 argument function to a function on the first 2 elements of a list. The arguments `x` and `y` are swapped since forth [seems to have the convention](http://www.forth.org/svfig/Win32Forth/DPANS94.txt) that the first argument pushed onto the stack is the first argument to the function and the argument on top of the stack is the second argument to the function.

```
lift2 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
lift2 f (x:y:zs) = f y x:zs
lift2 f _ = error "not enough data on the stack"
```

To interpret multiple commands, we break them apart with `words`, which splits a string at whitespace, interpret each command, and compose them all together.

```
composition :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
composition = foldl (flip (.)) id

interpretCommands :: String -> [Int] -> [Int]
interpretCommands = composition . map interpretCommand . words
```

Then we can interpret a string of commands by calling `interpretCommands` and passing it the initial (empty) stack. Here are both of your examples.

```
main = do
    print $ interpretCommands "1 2 +" []
    print $ interpretCommands "1 2 + 4 - 3" []
    print $ interpretCommands "10 5 / 3" []
    print $ interpretCommands "13 7 MOD 2 / 4 *" []
```

The output is

```
[3]
[3,-1]
[3,2]
[12]
```

Notice that `[3,-1]` is in the opposite order than you suggested, since `3` is on top of the stack and is therefore at the beginning of the list. (This is the behavior you predicted in your comment in `fourthadd`.)

Comment: Why do you need the `flip` in `composition`? And, kind of related to that, how would you expand (or modify) the code to make the division and mod operations work? Above, you had to use `substract` to get the right behavior for substraction. Thanks

Comment: When you compose two functions together `f . g`, `g` is applied first and then `f`. `foldl` repeatedly applies the function to the accumulated value and the first value of the list, in that order. For example, `foldl op 0 [1, 2, 3]` is `((0 'op' 1) 'op' 2) 'op' 3`. If we have a list of functions `[f, g, h, i, j]` and we want to compose them all together, performing `f` first, that would be `j . i . h . g . f`, which is in the opposite order. `flip` flips the order of the arguments to `.`.

Comment: @user178332 How to add division depends on which order the operands are pushed on to the stack. What order do you want them to be in?

Comment: So `"10 5 / 3"` should return [3,2]

Comment: @user178332 I edited the answer to include multiplication, division, and mod. I flipped the arguments in `lift2` to match your expectations.

Comment: Thanks, but interpretCommands "1 2 + 4 - 3" [] is returning [3,1] instead [3,-1]

Comment: Thanks for all the input so far, btw

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to actually swap the arguments inside `lift2`.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as Cirdec, but maybe this is a bit easier for a beginner to read:

```
-- Data type to represent a command.
data Command = Push Int | Add | Subtract deriving Show

-- Type synonym: a Program is a list of commands.
type Program = [Command]

-- Type synonym: a Stack is a list of Int.
type Stack = [Int]

-- The interpreter entry point.
interpretCommands :: String -> Int
interpretCommands str = runProgram (parseProgram str)

-- Parse a string and turn it into the corresponding Program.
parseProgram :: String -> Program
parseProgram str = map toCommand (words str)
    where toCommand "+" = Add
          toCommand "-" = Subtract
          toCommand x = Push (read x)

-- Run a Program on the empty stack, return the result at the top of the result stack.
runProgram :: Program -> Int
runProgram program = head (runProgram' program [])

-- Run a program on a given stack, return the result stack.
runProgram' :: Program -> Stack -> Stack
runProgram' [] stack = stack
runProgram' (command:rest) stack = runProgram' rest (runCommand command stack)

-- Run an individual command.
runCommand :: Command -> Stack -> Stack
runCommand (Push n) stack = n:stack
runCommand Add (n:m:stack) = n+m:stack
runCommand Subtract (n:m:stack) = n-m:stack
```

I've split out the program into two pieces: `parser` and `runProgram`.  The first takes the string and converts it into an abstract representation of the program to be run.  The second interprets this abstract representation.  This is a good separation to use in problems like this; for example, when you desire to write better parsing logic you can modify `parser` without having to worry about breaking the `runProgram` logic.

Comment: But if you tried to run this program "4 3", it should return a Stack containing [3,4]. But your code is returning just 3 (not even is a list). How would you fix that? Thanks.

Comment: @user224567893 `runProgram' (parseProgram "4 3") []` should do what you expect. `interpretCommands` is doing more than you expect; it is parsing the program with `parseProgram`, running it with `runProgram'`, and returning only the top of the stack with `head` (in `runProgram`).